# What order would Haskell evaluate 2 operands of the same precedence?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, operator-precedence

For a function that uses the same operand, e.g. `+` or `*` more than once, how will it evaluate it?

For example, in the following code:

```
prodOfThree :: Int -> Int -> Int
prodOfThree a b c = a*b*c
```

How would the following be evaluated?

```
prodOfThree (2+3) 4 2
```

This is as far as I've got:

```
=> (2 + 3) * 4 * 2
=> 5 * 4 * 2
```

And then I am unsure of whether it would multiply `5*4` first, `4*2` first or `5*4*2` all at once.

Comment: Don't forget that an optimizing compiler can choose any order of evaluation for an associative operator such as `*`. Further `f 1 * f 2 * f 3` might perform all the three calls to `f` first (in any order) and then perform the multiplications (in any order), or mix both somehow: precedence is unrelated to the evaluation order of the arguments. (Albeit of course data causality must be respected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask for an operator's *infixity* using ghci:

```
>>> :info (*)
class Num a where
  ...
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
        -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
infixl 7 *
```

Or you can [look it up on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-). A good way to search Hackage is with [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/).

Because `*` has infixity `infixl 7` this means it is *left-associative* and has precedence *7*. Therefore, `a * b * c` is `(a * b) * c`.

A more interesting example is an operator that does not have the mathematical property of associativity such as `-` (not to be confused with infixity, which it does have). The infixity is `infixl 6` and therefore `a - b - c` is `(a - b) - c`.

An example of a right-associative operator is `:`:

```
>>> :info (:)
data [] a = ... | a : [a]       -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
infixr 5 :
```

So `a : b : c` is `a : (b : c)`. Note that if it was left-associative then `a : b : c` would (probably) be a type error!

Comment: Ah brilliant. Thank you. I was specifically looking up how Haskell evaluates and didn't come across an example that explained this.